# how to reduce a string by introducing dots within specified range

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js

I wanted to introduce `...`  between a specified range, so that i can see the file `format`

Let say i have a *string* `sinchan is going to school in india.mp4`

Let say i want to introduce `...` between `pos/index` 16 till 19

My string will look like this:  `sinchan is going...in india.mp4`

***my pseudo code:***

```
function getFilename(str, startingDot, endingDot, maxLengthRequired) {
  str.(introduce `startingDot` till 'endingDot' do not exceed string length more than `maxLengthRequired`)
}

alert(insert("sinchan is going to school in india.mp4", 16, 19,31));
```

***output*** : `sinchan is going...in india.mp4` (might differ by a char or two)

please help me thanks in advance!!!

Comment: it looks like some assignment/homework. Please research and try to code on your own, and ask for help when you are stuck in code.

Comment: Hi! Please take the [tour] and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

```
let str = 'sinchan is going to school in india.mp4'
function trans (str, start, end, max) {
    if (start + 3 > max) return new Error('start add three should not more than max')
    let result = str.slice(0, start) + '...' + str.slice(end)
    if (result.length <= max) return result
    return result.slice(0, start + 3) + result.slice((start + 3 - max))
}
trans(str, 16, 19, 31)
```

Answer (score 0):

You will want to make use of [String.indexOf(searchValue)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)

Once you know the proper start index, taking into consideration the length of the word you are searching for, and end index then you will want to slice the string apart [String.slice(startIndex, endIndex)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice)